# I get an unary operator error when i use this code until [ $i -le 180 ]

Tags: shell, operator-keyword

When i use the following code

```
until [ $i -le 180 ]
```

I get this error

```
[: -le: unary operator expected
```

Comment: Which shell, and where do you define `$i`? Please show more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy to reproduce:

```
until [ $i -le 180 ]
do
    echo $i
    (( i++ ))
done
gash.sh: line 3: [: -le: unary operator expected
```

This is because `$i` is empty.  You can avoid having the error by using either:

```
until [[ $i -le 180 ]]
```

or

```
until (( $i <= 180 ))
```

However in both cases `$i` will evaluate to zero, so you must initialise `i` with something greater than 180 for the loop to run.